# Visual Studio 2010: browse the web within VS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Consider a developer who spends lots of time in Visual Studio. Hours are spent toiling on source code. Sometimes, he needs to search the web.

Can you browse the web right within Visual Studio? Consider all modern versions and SKUs of Visual Studio.

If so, are there any easy ways to launch that browser window?

Are there any gotchas in terms of:

- CSS support
- rendering engine problems
- session/cookie problems

**Keyboard Shortcuts**

- Ctrl-W, W
- Ctrl-Alt-R (thanks Guvante)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+R is the short cut, also found under View -> Other Windows -> Web Browser.

I don't know about any problems, but youtube works :).

Answer (score 2):

The built in browser is good old Internet Explorer, so make sure you're fully patched before venturing into the wilds.